# Load content from Tag with JGit

Tags: java, git, jgit

In Java I'm trying to load the content pointed by a tag of my git repository. I would like to have temporary access to the version subfolders that correspond to that tag. I've tried to use the `parseTag` method of `RevWalk`, but I'm not sure if this is the right way as I found in the documentation that `ObjectLoader` can be the highway to solve this. Still not sure which one should I use.

Comment: You can use the `CheckoutCommand` to checkout the revision to which the tag points into the work dir. If you are looking for something else, please clarify what 'load' and 'temporary access' means exactly.

Comment: By 'load' I mean, having a copy of the tag content. Each tag in my git project is a different version of the software.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the `CheckoutCommand` to checkout a tag into the working directory.

For example:

```java
git.checkout().setName("refs/tags/my-tag").call();
```

will checkout the tag `my-tag` into the work dir.

Note, however, that the operation leads to a [detached HEAD](http://alblue.bandlem.com/2011/08/git-tip-of-week-detached-heads.html). If that's not desied, you need to advice the `CheckoutCommand` to create a branch for you.

For example

```java
git.checkout()
    .setCreateBranch(true)
    .setName("my-branch")
    .setStartPoint("refs/tags/my-tag")
    .call();
```

will create and checkout a branch named `my-branch` that points to the commit referred to by `my-tag`.